# SKiasharp Setting Typeface with ttf file resulting in null

Tags: c#, xamarin, skiasharp

I am trying to load a ttf file into a Typeface in skiasharp
I followed instructions here:  [Loading a font in skiasharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494804/loading-a-font-in-skiasharp)

The stream is successful but when I assign the typeface...its null.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong and wondering if someone can help by telling me what I am doing wrong.  Below is a sample of what I am trying to do.

```
public static SKPaint SelectedtText => new SKPaint { Color = SKColors.Black, FakeBoldText = true, Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke, StrokeWidth = .6f };

using (var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyMobileApp.Resources.Fonts.RobotoRegular.ttf"))
{
   var result = SKTypeface.FromStream(resource);
   // even though result is not null setting the typeface its always null...why???
   SelectedText.Typeface = result;
}
```

Comment: what is `SelectedText`?

Comment: Im so confused. Can you not see the SKPaint SelectedText above the using statement?

Comment: no, I obviously didn't

Comment: Okay, let ask a different way, is not visible to you?  I can see it.  Anyway its SKPaint SelectedText.  No matter what I do, when I set the typeface its null even though the source was not null.  I have googled and googled and tried everything I can find but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I overlooked it.  It is there.

Comment: the first thing I would suggest is using a different font.  Possibly there is a problem with the one you are using

Comment: Thats the issue, I need to use that particular font.  Its been using by a device I am talking too and I need to ensure the font fits within certain size dimensions.  I will try a different ttf file and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I tried different ttf files, still null after assigning the value

Comment: Open an issue on their GitHub

Comment: I started a discussion but did not open an issue.  I will open an issue and see what they say.

Comment: I notice that you open an issue:https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/2390 on Github, you can continue following up there.